# PowerShell: Pipeline objects into pipeline objects

Tags: powershell

*I'm using Powershell 5 if that's relevant*

When adding a property to the current item in a pipeline:

I cannot refer to *$_* **until** I have fed it into *another* pipeline. **Why?**

```
# make some objects to pass around
$test = (0..3) | %{[pscustomobject]@{key1="v$_.1";key2="v$_.2"} }
#    GM = TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
# trying to use the current pipeline object
$test | Add-Member @{key3=$_.key1}
$test | ft *

key1 key2 key3
---- ---- ----
v0.1 v0.2     
v1.1 v1.2     
v2.1 v2.2     
v3.1 v3.2     

# try again, this time taking the current pipeline object...
#... and then putting it into another identical looking pipeline
$test | %{ $_ | Add-Member @{key4=$_.key1} }
$test | ft *

key1 key2 key3 key4
---- ---- ---- ----
v0.1 v0.2      v0.1
v1.1 v1.2      v1.1
v2.1 v2.2      v2.1
v3.1 v3.2      v3.1
```

I suspect it might be that the first one is implying something automatically and I haven't told the invisible/implied function to pass on $PSItem.

Comment: All arguments evaluated before pipeline is started. `[pscustomobject]@{ key1='something else' } | % { $test | Add-Member @{key3=$_.key1} }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All arguments are evaluated in the *current* [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes) before the command starts, regardless of being used syntactically in a pipeline. So `$test | Add-Member @{key3=$_.key1}` uses `$_` from the current scope, meaning it's not an element in `$test`.

To have `$_` evaluated for each element in the pipeline, a new scope should be created for each element via ScriptBlock (the code in curly braces) in `ForEach`, `Where` like `1..2 | ForEach { $_ }`, or in ScriptBlock parameters like `E`xpression in `select @{N='calculated property'; E={$_.foo}}`.

Comment: What you call _context_ is usually named _scope_. Script blocks open a new scope, in which variables may be defined that are not there in the outer scope.